# how to get updates from xml file with php?

Tags: php, xml

I am programming a livescore and statistics website and i want to link my site "which using php" to an xml page to help me get the updates of scores and data as soon as it happens. i have tried the following php code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.iddaa.com.tr/XML/IDDAAMACPROGRAMI/index.htm?iddaadrawid=05.12.2012&iddaadrawide=06.12.2012&foraccess=KSsec654");

print_r($xml);
```

it gives me the following error:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://www.iddaa.com.tr/XML/IDDAAMACPROGRAMI/index.htm?iddaadrawid=05.12.2012&iddaadrawide=06.12.2012&foraccess=KSsec654:22: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 10 and head in C:\wamp\www\test\11.php on line 2`

Note: i have tried another link "http://www.goalserve.com/samples/soccer_livescore.xml"
i could just print the information from that link.

could any body help me to get the xml file linked to my site correctly, please?

Comment: That's not a valid XML file so of course it's not working.

Comment: you might want to tidy::clearRepair() that xml feed before feeding it to simplexml_load_string(), hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$xml  = file_get_contents("http://www.iddaa.com.tr/XML/IDDAAMACPROGRAMI/index.htm?iddaadrawid=05.12.2012&iddaadrawide=06.12.2012&foraccess=KSsec654");
$config = array(
        'indent' => true,
        'clean' => true,
        'input-xml'  => true,
        'output-xml' => true,
        'wrap'       => false
);

$tidy = new Tidy();
$xml = $tidy->repairString($xml, $config);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: when i run your code i got the following message:               "Class 'Tidy' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\11.php on line 11"      i am working with WAMP server and my php version is 5.3.5 tidy dll is not active so i uncomentted the dll file for tidy and install the tidy files from http://pecl.php.net/package/tidy but i could not find how to install and configure them properly to make tidy class working so could you help me with that,please ?